# WPF Combobox auto complete/intellisense case sensitivity

Tags: wpf, combobox, autocomplete, intellisense

I am writing a WPF app that has a combo box in it that is populated with a list of names.  The problem I face is that the auto complete/intellisense feature ignores case sensitivity.  Is there a property in the control or a work around to enable case sensitivity on the auto complete/intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a simple property to enable case sensitivity, you would have to implement your own auto-complete to replace or supplement the built-in functionality.

Fortunately, others have done this and there are a few examples out there if you wish to go down this road:

See AutoFilteredComboBox in this [thread @ MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e52796d1-d58a-438b-aba1-59844d24f419).
Or solutions at these blogs: [Automatically Filtering a ComboBox in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx), [Building Filtered Combobox for WPF](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html)

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this applies to previous versions. However, in .Net 4.0 the WPF combobox has two properties `IsTextSearchEnabled` (autocomplete) and `IsTextSearchCaseSensitive`.